# Batch file to copy a file from one location to another with a self-generated folder name

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

So I run a game server and I have had an issue as of late with corrupted information. I currently have a bat file running to automatically restart the program if/when it goes down. I would like to add to that file to also copy a specific save file and save this file to a different folder that contains the date and time of the copy. I found quite a bit of information about the copying of a file and that seems easy enough, however I am unsure on how to have the bat file create a new folder for this file everytime it's ran.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET  src=D:\source
SET bdir=D:\backup

SET pre=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%-
SET pst=.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%

IF "%time:~0,1%" GTR "0"  SET bf=%pre%%TIME:~0,2%%pst%
IF "%time:~0,1%" LSS "0" SET bf=%pre%0%TIME:~1,1%%pst%

xcopy /krchief /z /-y %src% %bdir%\%bf% >> %bdir%\%bf%.log
```

result:

[image: log file at backup folder]